# Why are these characters dressed the same?

Tags: doctor-who, clothing, miraculous-ladybug

Adrien from Miraculous Ladybug and the Thirteenth Doctor are dressed almost exactly the same. Why?

[image: the two characters]

Comment: Adrien appears to be wearing [the Tenth Doctor's shoes](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vIxD_WpTvM0/UIhfXyEWTPI/AAAAAAAAHPw/5TLP3o_EnVQ/s1600/159807486746958942_OeqVUjxM_c.jpg).

Comment: They are super similar. They have black shirts with a prism band on the front, white coats, and blue pants. I doubt one is based on the other, but a third inspiration is very plausible.

Comment: Voting to close. Any answer would be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Astralbee - Not true as seen by the answer below.

Comment: @voldemortswrath--inp.repl.co I read the answer and it does not answer the question "why are these characters dressed the same". It just says someone else noticed it too.

Comment: @Astralbee - It still doesn't mean that all answers would be POB! There could be some reasoning, an interview, etc.

Comment: @voldemortswrath--inp.repl.co Perhaps the question should have been "Is there a connection?" and then the answer could be "no, and here's why...". My issue is with the question, not any answer. The votes show that users are finding it to be a low-quality question.

Answer (score 2):

The (superficial) similarity between the two characters was noted by [Thomas Astruc](https://twitter.com/thomas_astruc/status/928997880022687744?lang=en), creator of Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug, although the strong implication is that he was amused by the comparison rather than reaching for his phonebook to get his lawyer's number.

> **Thanks for the homage! We love your show too! <3**
> ♯[miraculousladybug](https://twitter.com/hashtag/miraculousladybug?src=hashtag_click)
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter - With spelling corrected](https://twitter.com/thomas_astruc/status/928997880022687744?lang=en)</sup></sub>

Note that the 'looks' are only superficially similar. Adrien is wearing a white shirt over black t-shirt with 5 (non-rainbow) stripes, blue denim jeans and generic orange sneakers. The Doctor, by comparison, is wearing teal three-quarter trousers with suspenders, brown boots, a navy blue t-shirt with nine ([scarf-inspired](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/11/09/jodie-whittaker-costume-doctor-first-picture/)) colours and a grey full length coat.

The creator of the Doctor Who outfit has given extensive interviews about the creative process that went into making her eclectic get-up.

> **Q2. What was your inspiration behind Jodie’s costume?**
>
> **A:** *Jodie and I met in secret a few times. She had already been through the audition process and had time to think about what she would like to wear. She sent me a load of images and photos that she had collected that meant something to her, in particular one image of a woman in braces and trousers in a period that was hard to define. It was a black and white image and a great starting point. The next thing she said was that she likes colour and wanted to incorporate it into her Doctor costume. I went ‘gulp’ and starting looking for references.*
>
> **Q3. What made you pick those colours on her costume?**
>
> **A:** *The colour is inspired from a variety of sources, one of the first photos Jodie showed me was a Coldplay album cover which was cool. She loves Coldplay and their use of colour was lovely. We also wanted to reference the colours of the sky and space and so the rainbow and the blues came into focus very early on. And in true synchronicity it also referenced the colours from previous Doctor’s costumes but in a gentle way. The rainbow colours are all muted. So colour was important and each one means something including the coat lining and the lining of the sleeves.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ray Holman - Costume Designer Q+A](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/doctorwho/entries/3cfd7b93-2e89-4fec-a7b9-8de903f454f5)</sup></sub>

Comment: Interestingly, the picture in the quoted tweet seems to be precisely the same one as asked about...

Comment: @DavidW - I suspect someone sent it to him. Or that he mocked it up himself, given that his tweet is in direct response to the BBC's tweet welcoming the new doctor.